# college degree to be awarded after completion

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the situation where a person **X** is currently studying in a college where they will obtain a degree **D** after graduating.

Is there a single (or maybe two) word **W** which is equivalent to saying "degree to be awarded after completion".

It should fit in the following use-case (part of a CV/Resume):

> Degrees awarded: M.S. in Electrical Engineering
>
> Degrees yet to be awarded: M.S. in Computer Science

to

> Degrees awarded: M.S. in Electrical Engineering
>
> W: M.S. in Computer Science

Comment: As I'm unaware of any degrees awarded prior to completion I fail to see why a term of such specificity is needed. W = award. W = degree...

Comment: "Studying" or "Reading" would do wouldn't they?

Comment: @PaulChilds If the person has obtained previous degrees, how would you separate those degrees from the ones which are yet to be obtained?

Comment: @JeffUK I am not sure if that'd work in a resume. "Studying: MS in Computer Science" sounds a bit odd.

Comment: Is this asking for information on how to format a CV, when you are still studying a degree - but have completed one already?

Comment: @Bilkokuya Yes. I basically need to separate out degrees already obtained and degrees which are yet to be obtained. As of now I have "degrees awarded:" and "degrees yet to be awarded:". The latter disturbs the visuals for being a bit lengthy.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that the student is somehow close to finishing (i.e. close to completing), or not necessarily—in other words, should **W** apply also to someone who has just started their studies for that degree?

Comment: @linguisticturn It's for someone who is half way through.

Comment: *Pursuing* (or *Currently pursuing*) might be an option. In the case of PhD, if the student has advanced to candidacy, *Candidate* would be appropriate.

Comment: Some sites recommend *in progress* (see e.g. [here](https://www.workitdaily.com/incomplete-degree-resume/)).

Comment: Why don't you say "Undergraduate student in Chemistry"?

Comment: In my CV I list my degrees, and where I have not completed the requirements for an award I put "(incomplete)" after the award name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of websites about how to write a CV recommend *in progress* (see e.g. [here](https://www.workitdaily.com/incomplete-degree-resume/)). Though usually those words are added *after* the degree description, it can also work as

*In progress: M.S. in Computer Science*.

Some other options are

*Pursuing: M.S. in Computer Science*
 
*Currently pursuing: M.S. in Computer Science*
*Working towards: M.S. in Computer Science*

In the case of a Ph.D., if the student has advanced to candidacy,

*Candidate: Ph.D. in Computer Science*

may work.